# Keep rows that has specific endings

Tags: r

I have rownames like this in a data.frame and want to keep only those which has `p__` followed by letters [`A-z]` and not a `|` sign. 
Tried this, but did not work:

```
grep("p__[[:alpha:]]$",rownames(df),  perl=T)
```

input:

```
p__xxxx|g_xxxx|s_xxxx
p__xxxx|g_xxxx
p__xxxx
```

output:

```
p__xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that there can be multiple letters after the underscores, using `+`.

```
x <- c('p__xxxx|g_xxxx|s_xxxx', 'p__xxxx|g_xxxx', 'p__xxxx')
grep("p__[[:alpha:]]+$",x)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a vector with your 3 strings:

```
str0<-"p__xxxx|g_xxxx|s_xxxx"
str1<-"p__xxxx|g_xxxx"
str2<-"p__xxxx"

mystr<-c(str0,str1,str2)
```

Then you can select using the following:

```
mystr[!grepl('\\|', mystr)&grepl("p__",mystr)]
[1] "p__xxxx"
```